# Obtain a reference to the Loopback middleware for use in another Express server instance

Tags: express, loopbackjs, middleware

I want to add a GUI to a Loopback application.

`react-boilerplate` uses an Express server, and gives the programmer a spot to add middlewares. It's fully featured, and I don't want to break it up and pull apart their middleware chain. I think I want to use this as an application starting point.

`loopback-cli` has a generator that generates a server with its own middleware and models. I want to preserve these models, and the `/api/*` endpoints that Loopback generates.

Is there a way to obtain a reference to the Express middleware created by Loopback, without starting a Loopback server, so that I can use that middleware in a react-boilerplate app server?

**Edit -** However, perhaps it's better to go the other way. Keeping the Loopback application as the starting point would me to add a static website that is generated by react-boilerplate.

Comment: just have two servers. it's easier and more common. react can be hosted by any old static hosting like github pages even. then hit your loopback server from there as needed. create-react-app is perfect for your react front end

Comment: I like this idea. thinking about the drawbacks, you'd have to launch two servers. i was hoping to have only one for simplicity. the GUI would need to use CORS if the API server is at another address

Comment: that's like 99% of apps nowadays

Comment: you can always setup a proxy to avoid cors like nginx

Comment: seems pretty trivial to add a static website middleware to loopback. i need to figure out how to edit middleware.json